# About the % applying with CSS

Tags: css

I am wondering exactly what is the reference of the % the CSS langage use. I have 2 questions to understand this process:

Why do we have to change the value for different devices resolutions (for example if i want to fit an element on the middle on the screen, why isn't it `margin-top: 50%;` good for every cases)?

Is there a way to use container as reference when applying a `%` on a child (like the `position relative` and `absolute` process)?

Comment: `margin-top:50%` is going to be "where the element begins vertically"

What i think you are asking is "how do i determine how far to offset an element i want positioned in the vertical center" ? or are you asking something else ?

Answer (score 0):

the answer:

1. % value is relative to parent width; `margin-top: 50%;` for 1024 x 768 means 512 from the top, `margin-top: 50%;` for 800 x 600 means 400 from the top. its definitely different from different resolutions.
2. % for what? height or widht?  if its for width its already refer to the parent(container). if its height, you can use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The interesting thing about the % value in CSS is that it's entirely relative to the parent element.  Think of it this way:

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content">Hello</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container, #content { width: 50%; }
```

The `#container` element will have a width of 50% which we see can assume the parent element to be the `body` tag since I didn't explicitly state a parent element.  This container is 50% of the width of the browser window then.  Meanwhile `#content` which sits inside of `#container` will have a width of 50% to the parent element (`#container`) which is already 50% of the browser width itself.  The total width of `#content` compared to the whole browser is therefore 25% (50% of 50%).

If you're trying to know the pixel value of a percent in CSS, the short answer is that... *you can't*.  If you want to determine this value in the form of a percent then you're going to need to use Javascript.  This isn't all bad though, but you should also understand that applying styles via Javascript isn't really the best of practices.  This should be done in the way of creating CSS classes and then using Javascript to add or remove those classes to change the style.  However, if you are just looking to have that pixel value and not change any CSS styles accordingly then what I just mentioned doesn't really matter.  Numbers are numbers at the end of the day, but the point of CSS was never to do arithmetic, it was meant to be an easy way to apply styles to HTML elements which originally inherited the styles defined by a browser.  Javascript was invented as a way to analyze data on the front-end and to create a dynamic presence to websites.  CSS was really never created for this purpose and that stands true to today's coding standards.